# javascript which makes cross domain GET requests and assigns it to a variable

Tags: javascript, http, cross-domain

for quite a long time i am looking for a javascript code which can make cross domain GET requests..
i want to make a javascript which makes a GET request to google and fetches the page source and assigns it to a variable..
note:the get requests must be generated from the clients computer and to a different server(eg:google)

Comment: That's just not possible: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: It's possible with [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). But, it's doubtful that Google or others would set "Allow" for screen scraping.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible due to the *same origin policy* which restricts AJAX and iFrames.

However, afaik Google offers a very own AJAX API to fetch search results, thats maybe enough for your needs.

But unless the Google servers don't allow for cross-domain calls (which I don't believe) there is no way in fetching data via a pure client-side AJAX connection.

---

<sup>Disclaimer: it might be possible in some browsers by changing some core settings</sup>